# ERROR CON JSON PARA PASAR CAMPOS DE FORMULARIO CON INFORMACION EN PYTHON Y REQUESTS

Tags: python-3.x, json, python-requests

Me encuentro con un problema de construir un Json correctamente con campos de un formulario para poder pasar datos.

Quiero enviar los datos y un pdf a un formulario con los siguientes datos:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tengo un json armado de esta manera que le estoy pasando como parametro data pero a la hora de ejecutar me sale el siguiente error:

[image: respuesta de api]

Y finalmente mi codigo hasta ahora es el siguiente:

```
import requests
import json
               
url_get = "https://api.nosconecta.com.ar/auth"
usr = {"user":"xxxxxxx", "password":"xxxxxx"}

r = requests.get(url_get, headers = usr) ## 
content_json = r.json()
pretoken = content_json['message']['token']
token = "Bearer " + pretoken


print(r.status_code)
print(" ")

         
url_post = "https://api.nosconecta.com.ar:443/file/"

payload = {'datos':{"ape_y_nom_afiliado":"Test","pedido_sap":"123456","usuario":"xxxxxxx@scienza.com.ar","nro_carnet": "00000555","id_interno_cliente": "00440033"},
'idaplicacion':'398'}

headers = {'accept':'application/json', 'Authorization':token, 'PYTHONHTTPSVERIFY':'0'}

response = requests.post(url_post, headers=headers, data = payload)

print(response.text)
```

Comment: Intenta con `requests.post(url_post, headers=headers, json=payload)` en vez de usar el parametro data

Comment: Hola aun asi continua dandome el mismo mensaje Incorrect JSON data field. Aparte tambien debo agregar subir un pdf al formulario el cual lo tengo de la siguiente manera files = [
 ('archivo', open('C:/Users/aalarcon/Desktop/PruebasProduc/200008596.pdf','rb'))
]

Comment: Otra cosa que se me ocurre, cambia el `payload = {'datos':{"ape_y_nom_afiliado":"Test", ...}, ...}` por `datos = {"ape_y_nom_afiliado":"Test", ...}; payload = {'datos': json.dumps(datos), ...}`